# Handle google recaptcha with python / requests form

Tags: python, json, urllib3

I was trying to find a way to fill a form then get the captcha response and found this code on stackoverflaw:

```
import urllib
import json


URIReCaptcha = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'
recaptchaResponse = body.get('recaptchaResponse', None)
private_recaptcha = '6LdXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
remote_ip = request.remote_addr
params = urllib.urlencode({
            'secret': private_recaptcha,
            'response': recaptchaResponse,
            'remote_ip': remote_ip,
})

# print params
data = urllib.urlopen(URIReCaptcha, params).read()
result = json.loads(data)
success = result.get('success', None)

if success == True:
    print 'reCaptcha passed'
else:
    print 'recaptcha failed'
```

I tried it, but it says 'body' is not defined.
So instead I tried 'requests.get' but I get tons of mistakes.

Any clue on how i could make this work??
moreover, to validate my form I only need to pass the captcha-response to the form to make it work??

Thank you all for your answers

EDIT: 
here is the link of the Post where i got it form: 
[How to validate a ReCaptcha response server side with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46393162/how-to-validate-a-recaptcha-response-server-side-with-python)

Comment: `recaptchaResponse = body.get('recaptchaResponse', None)` from where you get `body` ?

Comment: that's the problem, I have no idea... here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46393162/how-to-validate-a-recaptcha-response-server-side-with-python

Comment: this code is for flask, you need flass app

Comment: It should work in python 3 as well. I only need to find out what is the body. I can't find infos except this one that is clear enough to complete recaptcha form

Comment: in this code `body` is a dictionary and this dictionary have a key `recaptchaResponse` i don't know what are there, find a docs and make it

Comment: What kind of application are you writing? Are you trying to complete a reCAPTCHA on a web site, or validate the results entered for a reCAPTCHA on your own site?